# My 9398 crawler going in reverse way

Tags: technic, remote-control

I built 9398 crawler set and everything seemed OK.

However, when I moved the RC tumbler up, the crawler went back, and when I moved it down, the crawler went forward.

On the battery box I saw tumbler and changed its position, but nothing changed.
I also changed the order of connection motors to box, which also didn't help.

P.S. Turns work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the power functions FAQ:

> 7. Why does my Power Functions model drive backward when I want it to run forward? You can change the direction your model runs by flipping
>      the small black switches located on each side of the channel selector
>      of your IR Remote Control.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, you've already tried the little black switch on your remote, and that didn't fix things. I've had the same problem with PF remotes in the past, where one of those switches just stops working. Try unplugging the motors connected to the IR receiver, and swapping which port they connect to. Then see if the toggling works on the other side of the remote.

If the remote is at fault, try contacting LEGO customer service.