# Third power functions train runs backwards, why?

Tags: trains, power-functions

We have the passenger train and freight train, both run from a single controller - one through the red and one through the blue side. At Christmas we got the holiday train, and with the power functions kit coming back in stock with Lego, we just added power to it.

Having set this train to red on channel 2, its forward is counter clockwise. Both trains on channel 1 go forward when the dial is turned clockwise!

How do I reverse the controls of channel 2 without affecting channel 1?

Comment: Have you considered lifting the train off the track and turning it 180°?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My 9398 crawler going in reverse way](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9749/my-9398-crawler-going-in-reverse-way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power functions motor block is symmetrical except for where the power cable comes out:

[image]

So I think it likely you can (partially) rebuild your city train with the motor turned 180 degrees, which will clearly change the direction the train travels... 
Since I would expect all trains going in the same direction when exactly built according to the instructions, perhaps you oriented the motor wrong in the city train or the other two trains ?

Comment: Looking at it all closer Michael Verschaeve has it. The drive units on the 2 large trains are the rear bogey on the train thus the power cable comes out the front of the bogey. On the Holiday train the power is in the front wheels so the power comes out the back. As such the unit is reversed and the drive. Stupid I didn’t notice it but thinking now I may switch both the big trains onto one channel and reverse the other for the holiday train.

Answer (score 3):

There are little black switches on the train remote control which you can use to invert the direction.

[image]

Comment: The little black switches change the direction but of all the trains so the 2 trains on the red dial then reverse how they operate. This means the Christmas train and the blue train work turning the dial clockwise and the passenger train anti clockwise. Turning the train round to face the other way obviously makes no difference!

Comment: I see, you want the trains controlled by the same remote. Then my answer indeed doesn't help much, I'll post a different one

Comment: Any way to do this on the 88010 remote (or the 88009 hub / 88011 train motor)?

Comment: For the 88010 remote, you can physically turn the switch... (plus becomes in the minus position and vice versa), there are no additional control switches...